how to plot a nonlinear fit in ggplot
I am trying to add another study (Study 3) but it is a non linear equation. Is there a way I can add y = 841C^0.395 into ggplot so that it can be overlaid onto the other studies?
 df <- structure(list(cast = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), levels = c("20", 
 "38", "39", "40", "64"), class = "factor"), pressure = c(35, 55, 80, 30, 60, 
 90, 120, 10, 30, 105, 10, 25, 50, 150, 10, 30, 50, 110), A = c(41.16839801075, 
 30.35583650075, 22.86016618075, 37.62401496575, 42.10374747575, 
 29.76534520575, 19.89095365075, 34.60109149575, 36.46829997575, 
 10.79044853575, 10.074408825375, 14.411792332875, 18.009666975375, 
 2.072538610375, 21.176471287875, 29.320954852875, 33.385755602875, 
 12.881251150375), B = c(0.167453363918363, 0.17518132016261, 
 0.15617506189818, 0.151344619899147, 0.147003925515812, 0.126873347608938, 
 0.090790417919621, 0.163199854779293, 0.169272560643038, 0.0713129535723068, 
 0.095766197060871, 0.0959198565223836, 0.0942295291663098, 0.0236323199767932, 
 0.158893301040358, 0.152347661380295, 0.148441223978157, 0.0844843828480995
 ), C = c(0.00336278437771212, 0.00331746384695424, 0.0030822017959916,     
 0.00292870938310887, 0.00290212934310451, 0.00250957680053723,   
 0.00258302780282964, 0.0024001708579677, 0.00287706607094219, 0.00162719976673661, 
 0.00121769817135316, 0.00127846193728378, 0.00148592933354497, 
 0.000842030854863154, 0.00247519031767006, 0.00269025444986639, 
 0.00291526589547116, 0.00207540832089215)), row.names = c(NA, 
 -18L), class = "data.frame")


(plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = C, y = A)) +
geom_point() +  
theme_minimal() + 
geom_abline(aes(intercept = -6.2, slope = 13115.87, colour = "This study")) + # This study
geom_abline(aes(intercept = 9.43, slope = 380.7, colour="Study 2")))


For more general functions you can use geom_function:
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = C, y = A)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_minimal() +
  geom_abline(aes(intercept = -6.2, slope = 13115.87, colour = "This study")) + # This study
  geom_abline(aes(intercept = 9.43, slope = 380.7, colour = "Study 2")) +
  geom_function(aes(color = "Study 3"), fun = \(x) 841 * x^0.395)


A small drawback compared to geom_abline is that the function will only be plotted for the limits of the scale which default to the range of the variable mapped on x. Hence, geom_function will not account for the expansion of the scale whereas a geom_abline extends to the panel borders.
Besides removing the expansion one option to account for the expansion would be to manually set the limits for geom_function using xlim=. But as this affects the scale this also requires to set the limits to the original range using coord_cartesian:
ggplot(df, aes(x = C, y = A)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_minimal() +
  geom_abline(aes(intercept = -6.2, slope = 13115.87, colour = "This study")) + # This study
  geom_abline(aes(intercept = 9.43, slope = 380.7, colour = "Study 2")) +
  geom_function(aes(color = "Study 3"),
    fun = \(x) 841 * x^0.395,
    xlim = range(df$C) + .05 * diff(range(df$C)) * c(-1, 1)
  ) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = range(df$C))



You can add geom_line with a mutated data:
ggplot(df, aes(x = C, y = A)) +
  geom_point() +  
  theme_minimal() + 
  geom_abline(aes(intercept = -6.2, slope = 13115.87, colour = "This study")) + # This study
  geom_abline(aes(intercept = 9.43, slope = 380.7, colour="Study 2")) +
  geom_line(data=mutate(df, y=841*C^0.395), aes(y = y, col="Study 3"))



I think there might be a scaling issue? If it doesn't start from zero (or close to) is that a scaling issue?

The mutate is not necessary. You can simply use y = 841*C^0.395. However, be aware this will only add points for values present in the data. For the present use case the approximation might be sufficient. But for more curved functions you will probably end up with a bad approximation to the true shape for points which are further apart. geom_function instead uses a grid of n evenly spaced points where n defaults to 101.
